# Demote domain controller on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, iaas

I had been using Azure VM as domain controller. I had to demote this DC & remove AD DS & DNS role.
On reboot I am not able to connect to this VM using Remote desktop.

I tried following as the username with password:

1. vm name \ username
2. old domain name \ user name
3. MicrosoftAccount \ username

I suffered with this problem earlier, hence I had created another admin user user2 before installing domain controller, that also doesn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably to late for you, but I add it for future reference for other SO visitors.

I encountered the same problem. While demoting, one of the last steps requires you to [enter a new administrator password](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831457.aspx#BKMK_NewAdminPwdPage). After the reboot, my RDP connection failed for my local admin user, which I named 'vmadmin'. I finally discovered that the demoting renamed (or removed) my 'vmadmin' user, but assigned the new password to the 'administrator' user.
So try to login via RDP with user 'administrator' and your newly entered password.